# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'react_native_reanimated_1.EasingNode.bezier')

Tags: react-native

Has anyone ever had a problem like this? This happen when I using `react-native-skeleton-content`, please help me.
[this my screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGEWX.png)

Comment: Have you installed `react-native-reanimated`?

Comment: I already installed it. "react-native-reanimated": "^2.2.0" @Rohit

Comment: @karuniaandriansaputra try install `react-native-reanimated` `2.1.0` version because `react-native-skeleton-content` have locked dependencies https://github.com/alexZajac/react-native-skeleton-content/blob/master/package.json#L86

Comment: @karuniaandriansaputra Can you copy the text of the error into the question? It will help those searching for the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved, I need dependencies:

- `react-native-linear-gradient: "^2.5.6"`
- `react-native-reanimated "2.1.0"`
- `react-native-redash "^16.0.11"`

Its works on my case

Answer (score 2):

Add or change "react-native-reanimated": "^2.1.0", version in your package.json file. Its works for me